# Change alias after declaration

Tags: c++

I'm quite new in C++ programming. So I tried to define an alias and change it later, but I'm not sure if it is possible and (if it's possible) how to do it:

```
using Alpha = Alphabet::DNA
//I don' need the Alpha here, but I have to define it before the scope,
//because afaik if I define it inside the scope,
//it'll be lost outside the scope
for(int i = 0 ; i < argc ; ++i){
    if(argv[i] == "-d"){
        Alpha = Alphabet::DNA;
    }else if(argv[i] == "-r"){
        Alpha = Alphabet::RNA;
    }
}
Sequence<Alpha> seq;
```

I need to do this because I only know from the arguments which Alpha I have to use. Alphabet is already a namespace and DNA and RNA are "subtypes" of it.
Sequence is just a template class representing the sequence of molecules fro DNA or RNA.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You should probably define it only after you know that proper value.

Comment: You have to show what you have tried, what is your error to get full context for us to be helpful. BTW, you can change the alias in a new scope

Comment: Type aliases are a compile time feature.  You can't set one with run time arguments.  A more flushed out example of what you are trying to achieve would help us help you/

Comment: C++ is a statically typed language so decision on whether `Sequence<Alpha>` is `Sequence<Alphabet::DNA>` or `Sequence<Alphabet::RNA>` must be made during compilation and changing type of entities based on run time data is not possible. So you will need to implement two routines - one for `Sequence<Alphabet::DNA>` and another for `Sequence<Alphabet::RNA>`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **NO**.

For every type (alias or not), `cpp` compiler have to determine its "real type" in **compile time**.

For instance,

```
constexpr int N = 3;
using FixedBitset = std::bitset<N>;
```

is valid. While

```
int N = 3;
using FixedBitset = std::bitset<N>;
```

is definitely invalid because the value `N` cannot be checked out in compile time.